# How to achieve the same effect when it comes to background video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, frontend

H!

I have to achieve the same effect with background video in "hero" section (first below navbar) as on the given page: https://www.invisionapp.com/. Do yo have any idea what I could use if I have video in mp4 format? And also it should behave the same way as on the page - plays in full screen modal when click "play" button. Any video service provider, javascript library recommended?
Thanks in advance!
Best regards!

Comment: Hey, might wanna add what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

About the background video you could you a video tag with a z-level in css.
The z-level will put it a layer below whats above.
For example:

```
<video autoplay loop muted style="z-index: -1;">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But I am not sure how to implement the full screen modal, unfortunately.